# Using of custom typeface for drawing on canvas Java Android

Tags: java, android

I have a custom typeface which I have loaded in Typeface object with Typeface.createFromAsset(...). I need to drawing 1 symbom from this typeface with char-code 37 on canvas. I use this code:

```
String s=String.valueOf(((char)37));

Paint paint=new Paint();
paint.setTypeface(mNoteTypeface);
paint.setTextSize(30);

canvas.drawText(s, 20, 20, paint);
```

But result doesn't be good. I have the program for viewing fonts and one showed me that:
http://imagepost.ru/?v=qzvcgsbbxkldahdxuptuuvuyyugqlx.jpg

Help me to create a code, I'm very upset.

Answer (score 4):

code shown is correct.  Make sure `mNoteTypeface` contains custom font. Look for:

1. font file is in `assets\fonts` folder of project.
2. font files are case sensitive, `"fonts\deco.ttf"` will not work for `"Deco.ttf"` file:

> paint.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
>                       "fonts/Deco.ttf"));